# XCODE 8.2 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION i have made a AKSwiftSlideMenu and when i click on my new tap i get this error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: xcode

I have made a AKSwiftSlideMenu slide out menu bar and when i create a new tap i get an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error in this line of code

```
if (topViewController.restorationIdentifier! == destViewController.restorationIdentifier!) {
```

I have tried following the guide multiple times 
I have been following this guide  http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/09/create-your-own-slider-menu-drawer-in-swift/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Vadian, specifically in this case you have neglected to set the restoration identifier in Storyboard or code for those viewControllers - which the instructions do tell you to do, although not very clearly.

See [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial) on state restoration for how to do this in Storyboard (go to the section called 'Setting Restoration Identifiers').

But also learn about optionals and how to safely unwrap them - using ! is rarely a good idea.